# "yield" and "yield from" at same function

Tags: php, yield, yield-from

I need use `yield` and `yield from` at same function, but it seems not works as intended, once that it yields only the last `yield from` or `yield` (what comes last).

My code is (https://3v4l.org/jFDXh):

```php
function yieldItems() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield from [4, 5, 6];
    yield from [7, 8, 9];
}

var_dump(
    iterator_to_array(
        yieldItems()
    )
);
```

For all PHP versions it will only outputs `[ 7, 8, 9 ]`, but seems clear to me that it should be `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` instead.

However, if I do the same through a `foreach`, everything seems normal. It looks like it is a problem related to `iterator_to_array()`, but in fact, I need to convert this `Generator` to an array.

So, what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was concluding, I realized that the problem was really related to `iterator_to_array()`, so I decided to search more deeply in the [**PHP Documentation / Generators**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) and it shows precisely this type of problem.

Following the documentation:

> ***yield from* does not reset the keys**. It preserves the keys returned by the Traversable object, or array. **Thus some values may share a common key with another *yield* or yield *from***, which, upon insertion into an array, will overwrite former values with that key.
>
> A common case where this matters is ***iterator_to_array()* returning a keyed array *by default***, leading to possibly unexpected results. ***iterator_to_array()* has a second parameter *use_keys* which can be set to *FALSE*** to collect all the values while ignoring the keys returned by the Generator.

What this means, in general, is that when using **yield**/**yield from**, it will outputs keys too (the first **yield** will be `0`, for instance), just as it actually exists for pure arrays. So the code below will fail similarly (https://3v4l.org/pWeWT):

```php
function willOutputSingle() {
    yield 'sameKey' => 'originalValue';
    yield 'sameKey' => 'otherValue';
}

var_dump(
    iterator_to_array(
        willOutputSingle()
    )    
); 

// Outputs: [ 'sameKey' => 'otherValue' ]
```

It will happen because we yields to pairs like `[ 'sameKey' => 'originalValue' ]` and then `[ 'sameKey' => 'otherValue' ]`, so when we converts it to array, via `iterator_to_array()` the results is basically that:

```php
[ 'sameKey' => 'originalValue',
  'sameKey' => 'otherValue ]
```

But how PHP does not allows identical keys, only the last one is preserved.

**The solution** to this is pass `false` as second argument to `iterator_to_array()`, because it will not preserve keys yielded, so result will be an zero-index array. The result will be:

```php
[ 0 => 'originalValue',
  1 => 'otherValue' ]
```